# How can we edit parameter of multiple Jenkins job simultaneously?

Tags: jenkins, parameterized-tests

I have multiple parameterized Jenkins jobs to run multiple tests. I need to update one parameter of all the Jenkins jobs. Instead of changing the parameters one by one, is there a way to edit all the jobs simultaneously?

I tried to edit manually, but there are a lot of jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the [configuration slicing](https://plugins.jenkins.io/configurationslicing/) plugin to change parameters simultaneously in multiple jobs. It saves tons of work.

Answer (score 0):

All the configs of Jenkins jobs are located in the JENKINS_HOME/jobs. There is a folder for each job there which contains a config.xml that holds all information about that job including parameters. If all your parameters have the same name, you could consider using a tool to bulk find and repalce the parameters like this.